# Navbar link item not working, that means that is not redirecting to the id, (this is a single page application)

Tags: jquery, css, angular, bootstrap-4

```html
   

 <!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-3 sticky-top navbar-light bg-white">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#acasa">
      <img class="logo" src="./assets/img/xxxxx_psiholog_logo.png" alt="xxxxxx">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"  href="#acasa" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" >Acasa</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#servicii" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Servicii</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#despre-mine"data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Despre mine</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#tarife">Tarife</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sedinte"data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Sedinte</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#team"data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Casete</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog"data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact"data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="tel:xxxxxxxxx" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">
            <span><i class="bi bi-telephone contact">&nbsp;xxx.xxx.xxx</i></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="mailto: contact@dandurbaca.ro" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">
            <span><i class="bi bi-envelope contact"> contact@xxx.ro</i></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav><!-- //NAVBAR -->
```

The redirect works if i remove "data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" from the code, but i need that code to autoclose navbar when the link is clicked on mobile.
So i need a way to autoclose the menu when the link is clicked or to work the redirect.
I`m using angular, bootstrap

Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you using javascript,  coding close button with javascript try.

Example:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("button-id").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("button-id").style.width = "0";
}
```

or you can try adding javascript framework code for bootstrap.